# Software for cellular automota

Tags: simulation, software, software-recommendation

I would like to do simulations using cellular automata to describe the behavior of influenza. What software do you recommend?

Answer (score 3):

Well *Mathematica* provides a reasonable amount of intrinsic functionality for working with Cellular Automata.  It's not an area of the system I have extensive experience of and I don't know how it compares with other software with similar functionality.  You might learn more about it's CA capabilities before breaking open your piggy-bank (maybe digging into your trust fund too, *Mathematica*'s not cheap) over at the sister site https://mathematica.stackexchange.com.

Beyond that, I'd have thunk that programming CA's isn't tremendously difficult in many programming languages.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try Ready https://gollygang.github.io/ready/ especially if you are going for continous valued/reaction diffusion/FDTD type systems:

> Ready is a program for exploring continuous and discrete cellular automata, including reaction-diffusion systems, on grids and arbitrary meshes.

For discrete systems, [hashlife](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashlife) is a great algorithm to be able to efficiently step through millions of iterations, especially if parts of the pattern just oscillate. It is implemented in Golly http://golly.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

CellularAutomata.jl is a fairly efficient CA simulation package.

https://github.com/MartinuzziFrancesco/CellularAutomata.jl